# How to be sure that one or more third party plugins are secure enough to install to an app?

Tags: security, xss

We require components and plugins that improve UX by allowing users to pick dates and choose items from lists etc. We can build them manually and spend a lot of time on these, or we can search for pre-existing solutions online.

Those plugins and frameworks are usually free or community-built projects and therefore you cannot guarantee they are secured from common attacks such as XSS injection. Those attack vectors can provide an attacker with lots of valuable information about our projects without causing any visible harm to our project.

How do I prevent this? Is there a proper way to test a third party plugin before using it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**There isn't**

Realistically speaking, there isn't any way to guarantee a plugin is 100% secure. Some plugins are added to WordPress websites, or incorporated into projects, or even set as international standard protocols and they still have vulnerabilities. If you're interested, take a look at the recent *WPA2 KRACK* vulnerability that caused a lot of trouble.

Sadly, this is a risk you are going to have to take installing any plugin, anywhere, for anything. There have been a number of apps in the Google Play store containing viruses and vulnerabilities *designed* to give hackers access. There are still a lot of vulnerable or malicious plugins in the Google Chrome store that anyone can download. WordPress has some terrible plugins that offer a lot of weak points for seemingly no reward. There isn't really any other way out of an insecure plugin than to simply not use it.

**What you can do about it**

**1)** Take a look to see what security tests have been done. Do they have any certifications or compliance checks? Do they have any badges on their website to prove they regularly test and maintain their application for vulnerabilities?

**2)** Is it open source? This is a big one! Not only does being open source mean anyone can view the code, it means anyone can edit the code and redistribute their own version. Be sure to download a version of the plugin from a reliable source and check over their code. If you can see any vulnerabilities in it, chances are so can hackers. However, open source projects will often have vulnerabilities found much quicker than traditional [black box](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_box) programs do. This means there are usually less well known vulnerabilities or weak points which would be difficult to exploit or provide useless information, but this is not always the case.

**3)** Test it yourself? If you're unsure and really want to be extra careful, you can test the plugin for yourself (or get someone to test it for you). Some companies will do a professional job for you, but will charge a fee. Some online folks are often happy enough to test them and see what they can find (bug bounty hunters are a thing). Even just asking a friend who knows what they're doing, or googling some common hacks or injection scripts / tools is a good first step into testing something; and let's face it - it's better than nothing at all!

**4)** Avoid it! If you really can't be sure and don't want to take the risk, you can simply avoid the plugin and either create the item yourself (which could be, in some cases, even less secure or not as well built) or you can opt for a different solution or plugin. So if you find that PluginFoo seems fishy or insecure, you could opt for PluginBar instead.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer.